# Getting a Bit from SqlServer into c#

Tags: c#, sql

I need to get a Bit from a sql server into c#. I tried differnt solutions like:

```
bool active = rdr.GetSqlBinary(5);
Int16 active = rdr.GetSqlBinary(5);
```

But can't find any way to get the Bit.
Can someone give an example?

Comment: On a side note, you can make your code a little more readable/maintainable by using GetOrdinal() eg: rdr.GetSqlBoolean(rdr.GetOrdinal("MyBitColumn"))

Comment: I have also tried:
bool active = rdr.GetSqlBoolean(12);
I get the result: can't convert SqlBoolean to bool

Comment: Hi, you are missing a cast, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're certain that the column values will never be `NULL` then the following will do the trick:

```
bool active = rdr.GetBoolean(rdr.GetOrdinal("Active"));
```

If it's possible that `NULL` values might be returned:

```
int oActive = rdr.GetOrdinal("Active");
bool? active = rdr.IsDBNull(oActive) ? (bool?)null : rdr.GetBoolean(oActive);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [GetSqlBoolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlboolean.aspx) method.

**Update**

Make sure you cast your return value as a boolean i.e.

```
var active = (bool)rdr.GetSqlBoolean(5);
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote please specify why? Makes no sense to downvote an answer without giving a reason...

Comment: `SqlBoolean` is effectively just a wrapper around a boolean to allow for nullability etc. So if you're going to call `GetSqlBoolean` and then immediately cast the result to `bool` you might as well just call `rdr.GetBoolean` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

use GetFieldType to determine that data type to use.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at the following solution using:

```
bool active = (bool)rdr.GetSqlBoolean(rdr.GetOrdinal("Active"));
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use GetOrdinal, the GetSqlBoolean should be sufficient. They both have the same return type...

Comment: You can't upvote on StackOverflow until you have... 15? reputation points, which you earn by getting upvotes yourself, selected answers, and badges.  I think you should be able to mark a particular answer as the chosen answer, however.

Comment: `SqlBoolean` is effectively just a wrapper around a boolean to allow for nullability etc. So if you're going to call `GetSqlBoolean` and then immediately cast the result to `bool` you might as well just call `rdr.GetBoolean` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There is a public get method of SqlBoolean struct: IsTrue. So you can use it this way, to be sure that result is boolean:

```
bool active = rdr.GetSqlBoolean(5).IsTrue;
```