# Iterate through list of objects to check value

Tags: c#, list

I've found many similar questions on here but none of the answers seemed to help me. I'm new to C# and I feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. 
Anyway, I have a BIT columns in a SQL database. I'm trying to pull that data and check if they're true and if they are output that Object's name to a listbox in a windows form. I hope I explained that well enough... Here is the code.

First I created a class of all the items I'd be using

```
public class lb1items
{
    public string item1 { get; set; }
    public string item2 { get; set; }
    public string item3 { get; set; }
    public string item4 { get; set; }
    public string item5 { get; set; }
    public string item6 { get; set; }
    public string item7 { get; set; }
    public string item8 { get; set; }
    public string item9 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I query the database and put the items into a DataTable then pull from the datatable into the list

```
List<lb1items> varslist = new List<lb1items>();
varslist.Add(new lb1items()
{
    item1 = (dt.Rows[rowIndex]["Item1"].ToString()),
    item2 = (dt.Rows[rowIndex]["Item2"].ToString()),
    item3 = (dt.Rows[rowIndex]["Item3"].ToString()),
    item4 = (dt.Rows[rowIndex]["Item4"].ToString()),
    item5 = (dt.Rows[rowIndex]["Item5"].ToString()),
    item6 = (dt.Rows[rowIndex]["Item6"].ToString()),
    item7 = (dt.Rows[rowIndex]["Item7"].ToString()),
    item8 = (dt.Rows[rowIndex]["Item8"].ToString()),
    item9 = (dt.Rows[rowIndex]["Item9"].ToString())
});
```

Up to here everything works fine when I debug I can open varslist and see all the items with their true false value, here is where I'm having an issue.

I do a `for` loop, against `varslist.count()`, but when I debut it only gives me a value of 1 instead of 8? and it doesn't seem the check the value of the item against the if statement and definitely doesn't add anything to the checkbox, here is the code

```
for(int i = 0; i < varslist.Count(); i++)
{
    if (varslist[i].ToString() == "True")
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(varslist[i]);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Thank you for looking!

EDIT: What I'm trying to accomplish is add the bit Column Names from the DB whos value == true to the listbox.

Edit2: Couldn't figure it out the way I wanted to so instead I created a method that checked took the column name as a string then if that column was true it added it to the listbox

```
    public void addtoListBox(string fName)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[rowIndex][fName].ToString() == "True")
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(fName);
        }

    addtoListBox("Item1"..."Item9");
```

Comment: Are "item1"..."item9" supposed to be rows or columns? The way you have it now, they're columns, which would only yield a Count()==1. -- Also, `varslist[i].ToString()` is actually calling `ToString` method in your `lb1items` class, not getting the value (as I believe you suspect).

Comment: In the code above you add exactly one instance of lb1Items to your varList collection. This is why varslist.Count() is 1. Then you compare varsList[I].ToString() which is probably not what you want to do but rather compare to varslist[I].item1 or similar. Lastly your code contains no checkbox.

Comment: [If the column is defined as BIT you could use `GetBoolean` instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335066/getting-a-bit-from-sqlserver-into-c-sharp)

Comment: @BradChristie So they're columns in the database so I guess they're columns in the DT too? To your also, I just took off the tostring and see exactly what you mean. I'll try to work through this using your comment..

Comment: As a side : why you've defined 9 string properties instead of a List of string in `lb1items` class?

Comment: @user469104 Ok this makes sense I'll see if I can work through this using your information.

Comment: @S.Akbari I don't have a good answer for this, I did it this way because I found a write up on MSDN and this is the way they suggested?

Comment: use List<string> vaslist List<string>() its better option to define 9 string properties.

Comment: Yep, you've only added one lblItems object to your list, so that's all it's going to display. You'd have to interrogate each item1, item2, etc, in your current model, to get access to that single object's properties. Doesn't look like the right data model to me though. Not a good idea to have multiple properties called item1, item2, etc. That should be an array at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is like S.Akbari has stated, you are using an object with distinct properties rather than an enumerable collection of values.

Your code should look something more like this to be able to iterate over the collection of columns/values.

```
List<string> varslist = new List<string>();

var rowIndex = 0;
foreach (var col in dt.Columns)
{
    varslist.Add(dt.Rows[rowIndex][col.ToString()].ToString());
}

foreach(var value in varslist)
{
    if (value == "True")
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, however it adds "True" to listbox1 when true is found, it doesn't add the column name where true was found, that is what I am trying to get in the listbox, the Column Names whose values are true. I'm sorry I didn't accurately explain that I'll edit my original request.